# How to Get Log All MSExcel Event in text file in c#

Tags: c#, service, window

I want to Get Log of All the Excel Event like added new row enter value delete Cell or row 
apply any formula these all event should be log in text file

any suggestion on this implementation

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented code like when user open the Excel and press the Enter,ESC,and other single key and Combination of keys that i can get the log in text file using Hook.

Now i also want to Log when user Click on Cut,Copy,Paste button in Excel MenuBar
so How we can get That event log in C# Application ?